# Generate random password

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have this script in PowerShell. I want set up random password for each user import from file and I want all comments in popup cmd I want save in other txt file. How can I make this?

```
#
# Description: Enable accounts, reset passwords and set change password option at first logon.
#
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
# Set default password "XXX"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText “XXX” -Force 
# get account list from UserList.txt
# 1 user per line 
$users = Get-Content -Path 'G:\Shares\XXX\ResetPassword\UserList.txt'
ForEach ($user in $users) 
{
# Set default password for account
Get-ADUser $user | Set-ADAccountPassword -NewPassword $password -Reset
# Set option to change password at first logon
Get-ADUser $user | Set-AdUser -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true
# Enable account
Enable-ADAccount -Identity $user
Write-Host “Password change for: $user”
}
Write-Host “New password for all users: XXX”
# ————- End ———–
Read-Host -Prompt "Click enter to quit"
```

Comment: You are giving the same password to all users?

Comment: yes, but now i want to give random passwor for each user

Answer (score 9):

You can use the static [`GeneratePassword`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.generatepassword.aspx) [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) method to generate a password:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
[System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword(10, 3)
```

**Edit:**

You have to change your script to:

```
#
# Description: Enable accounts, reset passwords and set change password option at first logon.
#
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
$unsecuredPwd = [System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword(10, 3)
# Set default password "XXX"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $unsecuredPwd -Force 
# get account list from UserList.txt
# 1 user per line 
$users = Get-Content -Path 'G:\Shares\XXX\ResetPassword\UserList.txt'
ForEach ($user in $users) 
{
# Set default password for account
Get-ADUser $user | Set-ADAccountPassword -NewPassword $password -Reset
# Set option to change password at first logon
Get-ADUser $user | Set-AdUser -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true
# Enable account
Enable-ADAccount -Identity $user
Write-Host "Password change for: $user"
}
Write-Host "New password for all users: $unsecuredPwd"
# ————- End ———–
Read-Host -Prompt "Click enter to quit"
```

Comment: `$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText ([System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword(10, 3)) -Force`

Comment: Now i have and i dont see password in cmd. And How to mark text as code at Stackoverflow?
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
# Ustawia domyslne haslo na "xxx"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText ([System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword(10, 3)) -Force
...
Write-Host “uzytkownik: $user”
Write-Host “haslo: $password”

Comment: Okay, I posted the whole script so you can copy paste it. You can use backticks to mark text as code.

Answer (score 1):

@MartinBrandl's answer works but requires importing `System.Web.` Below is a bespoke solution that'll generate a random printable ASCII string using the system's cryptographic generator and a little bit of maths; sample usage: `[SecureRandom]::GeneratePassword(64)`. Integrating into a script is left as an exercise for the reader...

```
class SecureRandom {
    hidden static [System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator] $m_randomNumberGenerator = ([System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider]::new());

    hidden static [System.UInt32] NextUInt32([System.UInt32]$exclusiveHigh) {
        [System.UInt32]$range = ([System.UInt32]::MaxValue - ((([System.UInt32]::MaxValue % $exclusiveHigh) + 1) % $exclusiveHigh));
        [System.UInt32]$result = 0;

        do { # perform rejection sampling to avoid bias; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling, https://www.pcg-random.org/posts/bounded-rands.html
            $result = [SecureRandom]::NextUInt32();
        } while ($result -gt $range);

        return ($result % $exclusiveHigh);
    }

    static [System.String] GeneratePassword([System.UInt32]$length) {
        $result = [char[]]::new($length);

        for ($i = 0; ($i -lt $length); ++$i) { # generate a random ASCII character within the "printable" decimal range of 32-126; this currently "wastes" 3 bytes per iteration and could be made more efficient...
            $result[$i] = ([char][SecureRandom]::NextUInt32(32, 126));
        }

        return [System.String]::new($result);
    }
    static [byte[]] GetBytes([int]$count) {
        [byte[]]$result = [byte[]]::new($count);

        [SecureRandom]::m_randomNumberGenerator.GetBytes($result);

        return $result;
    }
    static [System.UInt32] NextUInt32() {
        return [System.BitConverter]::ToUInt32([SecureRandom]::GetBytes(4), 0);
    }
    static [System.UInt32] NextUInt32([System.UInt32]$x, [System.UInt32]$y) {
        if ($x -gt $y) {
            $z = $x;

            $x = $y;
            $y = $z;
        }

        [System.UInt32]$range = ($y - $x);

        if ($range -ne [System.UInt32]::MaxValue) {
            return ([SecureRandom]::NextUInt32($range + 1) + $x);
        }
        else {
            return [SecureRandom]::NextUInt32();
        }
    }
}
```